# Transforming an input variable into an interger

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, while-loop

I'm completely new to python, and I wanted to create a program that "loads" a number that the user would have entered.

To do this, I made a function with an input variable,

> percentage

that I then tried to transform to an interfer,

> percentage_int

To then put in a while loop.
However, I get an error message, why?

```
def loader():
     percentage = input("what percentage do you want?")
     percentage_int =int(percentage)
     x = 0
     print("Goal:{} %".format(percentage_int))

    while x < percentage_int:
         x+=1
         print(x)
```

loader()

Comment: `percentage_int =(percentage)` just sets `percentage_int` to exactly the same value as `percentage`. It's a string.

Comment: percentage_int =  int(percentage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do the type conversion, that is in this case from string to integer.
If you dont do so python will consider percentage_int as the input string itself.

```
    percentage = input("what percentage do you want?")
    percentage_int = int(percentage)
```

Go through this [tutorial](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/SimplePythonData/Typeconversionfunctions.html) which will help you learn more about type conversions with python.